# Raw liver keeping time in alcohol

Tags: liver

I want to make some chicken liver pate and have some raw livers soaking in my fridge. They’ve been soaking in the brandy and port and some sage and rosemary for about 2 weeks. They smell and taste fine but does anyone know how long the alcohol will preserve them? How would I know if they’re no longer edible? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is no tested safe method for home conserving meat with alcohol. This means thata your safety time is as unpreserved meat, which is up to 5 days in the fridge.

Comment: Yes, thanks. The livers smelt absolutely fine, but of course, brandy has a strong smell. So they ended up in the bin.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the recipe you are using ?

Recipes I've seen soak the liver for at most a couple of hours; most recipes do not soak in alcohol, but in milk, or no soaking at all.

Two weeks is way too much, I would not use those livers.

Comment: The recipe was for chicken liver pate which I’d made before and it was delicious. But I’d got busy and the time flew - I really hate wasting food which is why I asked the question hoping someone might miraculously tell me alcohol could keep raw meat safe for weeks:-} . But it was too risky so I’ll just have to be organised next time I get the livers prepped.